# Filter through tasks and retrieve names

Tags: c#

this is my first question on the site although I have gotten lots of help from it already.

What I am looking to do is to open a MSProject (.MPP) document and look through all the task names, then only retrieve the ones with a specified name.

I have found a bit of code on this site [NerdyHearn](http://www.nerdyhearn.com/blog/156/) which seems to suit my needs, but for some reason I can only retrieve the name of the absolute first task?
Which seems strange to me since this line of code here:

```
    foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.MSProject.Task task in proj.Tasks)
    {
    }
```

Is a loop right? I have tried with different .MPP files and even created my own, but it still only retrieves the first one.

And if someone can help me to design a filter to use when retrieving the task names that would be great!

I have also tried to find documentation for Microsoft.Office.Interop.MSProject but I really can't seem to find it.

Comment: Maybe the Task class has a collection of subtasks and there are the task you are looking for

Comment: I think you may be on to something, I think that using task.Name is wrong, for example if you write Console.WriteLine(proj.NumberOfTasks); it displays '89' which is right. Now I only need some way of actually making it print out the names.

You can print out other tasks if you manually add successors in Microsoft Project and then write Console.WriteLine(task.SuccessorTasks); but then we would have to back track too far..

Comment: it works for me, but I tried on a very simple file. Can you share one of the mpp files that gives you the problem?

Comment: I'm not following either. Using the code provided, except that I used Application projApp = new Application(); instead of ApplicationClass, I get tasks and their subs. Task.Name is correct (for me). A file would definitely be helpful.

Comment: Not sure and just as idea, try to get the Name using the GetField property instead of Name property such as:   task.GetField(PjField.pjTaskName)

Answer (score 1):

Posting the code block so that you see what I have. Please post a file if you could, perhaps its something else instead of subtasks as I have 4 levels in some spots and all my tasks come out as expected.

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.MSProject;
using System;
using System.Reflection;
namespace PProject
{
    public class Program
    {
         public static void Main()
         {

             Application projApp = new Application();
             projApp.FileOpenEx(@"C:\Tickets.mpp", true, Missing.Value, 
             Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, 
             Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value,
             PjPoolOpen.pjDoNotOpenPool, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, 
             Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value);

             Project proj = projApp.ActiveProject;

             // Enumerate the tasks
             foreach (Task task in proj.Tasks)
             {
                 string name = task.Name;

                 Console.WriteLine(task.Name);
             }

             // Make sure to clean up and close the file
             projApp.FileCloseAll(PjSaveType.pjDoNotSave);
             }
     }
 }
```